# Array List printing wrong numbers

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am trying to write a program to take in a set of results of an exam and print them out in a histogram.  I am writing the code in stages and at this moment I am trying to get it to take in the exam marks and then print them out in a list just to make sure it is working before moving on to the histogram.

My problem is that when I input my numbers into my array and then print them I get a weird number coming up, say for example I enter the numbers 1,2,3,4

Expected console output:
1
2
3
4

Actual output:
-858993460
1
2
3
4

so I know this must be a problem with my code however I am not sure what can anyone help please?

Code:

```
void readExamMarks(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray){

   cout << "Please enter a set of exam marks to see a histogram for:" << endl;
   for( int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
      cin >> x;
      examMarks[x] = x;
   }
}

void printExamMarks(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray){

    system("cls");
    for(int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){

        cout << examMarks[x] << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{ 
    int examMarks[5];

    readExamMarks(examMarks, 5);
    printExamMarks(examMarks,5);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Writing code in stages and making sure each is working before moving on is exactly the right way to do it. Clearly you'll go far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reusing `x` for both your array index and the data:

```
for( int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
    cin >> x;
    examMarks[x] = x;
}
```

You need to use a separate variable for the array index:

```
int x = 0;
for( int idx = 0; idx < sizeOfArray; idx++){
    cin >> x;
    examMarks[idx] = x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This was really helpful, Since you answered first I will mark this one as correct once I can.

Comment: Glad that it helped! Since this is C++, you should also consider using a [`std::vector`](http://www.apitalk.com/c-And-C-Plus-Plus-Programming/Using-Vector-Instead-Of-Arrays-To-Prevent-Most-Of-Memory-Leaks.html)  instead of a pure array

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
for( int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
   cin >> x;
   examMarks[x] = x;
}
```

You are using the `x` as array index, and always accepts `x` as input value.

Answer (score 1):

```
for( int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
    cin >> x;
```

You are reading into the loop iterator. It should be

```
int temp
for( int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
    cin >> temp;
    examMarks[x] = temp;
```